# Clear cache CCTV script

Tags: batch-file, caching, memory, scheduled-tasks

I've got an issue with the cache on my web browser when running my iCatcher CCTV software. The cache fills up overtime which causes the computer to grind to a halt because the memory is being filled up by the cache.

I've tried setting a cache limit, but that doesn't seem to work.

What I'm asking is if it is possible to create a `.bat` file which would manually delete the cache every time my college logs on or off and then set it as a task to run in task scheduler?

Comment: Yes it is. Now try it yourself. Stack Overflow is a place where people encounter issues with their code and asks for help.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete to due the lack of code and the information about `iCatacher`.

---

Since cache may be held by `iCatcher` software and cannot be removed, we need to stop it first. (Change `iCatcher.exe` to your exact software name)

```
taskkill /f /im iCatcher.exe
```

Then we remove the cache, using `del`

```
del /f /q cache.ext
```

**F**orcefully, and **q**uitely remove `cache.ext`, also change `cache.ext` to your own cache name.

Finally, we start `iCatcher` back.

```
start "" Foo\Bar\Baz\iCatcher.exe
```

Change this to you software name.